# Specifying minor ticks on both yaxes

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a plot with two different yaxes and I am trying to set MinorTickValues on both. I can turn them on on both axes, which works fine. However, when I specify the location of them they disappear on the other axis.

```matlab
V = horzcat((-2:0.1:2), (2:-0.1:-2));
t = (0:0.01234568:1.01);
T = (0:25:2025);

figure(30);   
yyaxis right
plot(t ,V, 'Linewidth',3); hold all;
xlabel('Time / s');ylabel('Voltage / V');
set(gca,'FontSize',fontsize, 'LineWidth',2,'TickLength',[0.025 0.025])
xticks([0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]);
ylim([-2, 2]),
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.MinorTick = 'on';
ax.XAxis.MinorTickValues = (0:0.05:1);
set(ax.YAxis, 'MinorTick', 'on')
set(ax.YAxis, 'MinorTickValues', (-2:0.25:2))
    
yyaxis left
top = plot(t ,T, 'Linewidth',3); hold all;
xlabel('Time / s');ylabel('Temperature / K');
ax = gca;
%ax.YAxis.MinorTick = 'on';
%ax.YAxis.MinorTickValues = (250:50:650);
set(ax.YAxis, 'MinorTick', 'on')
set(ax.YAxis, 'MinorTickValues', (250:50:650))
chH = get(gca,'Children');
set(gca,'Children',[chH(end);chH(1:end-1)]);
uistack(top, 'top');
```

What it looks like now:

[image]

When setting the MinorTickValues on the left axis, the MinorTicks on the right axis disappear and vice versa.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it help if you do not overwrite your axes variable names? i.e. `ax_left = gca()` and then `ax_right = gca()`?

Comment: No it does not. I tried giving them individual names and set the MinorTickValues for all axes after configuring everything else. The result is still the same. Whichever axes I call last is showing the values and the other is not. Further, I looked at `ax.Yaxis.MinorTick` and it returns that both axes have the `MinorTicks` set to 'on'.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of yyaxis, it says "An exception is that the YAxis property of the Axes object contains an array of two ruler objects (one for each y-axis)." So you should be able to change the ticks with ax.YAxis(1), ax.YAxis(2)

```
fontsize = 10;

V = horzcat((-2:0.1:2), (2:-0.1:-2));
t = (0:0.01234568:1.01);
T = (0:25:2025);

figure(30);   
yyaxis right
plot(t ,V, 'Linewidth',3); hold all;
xlabel('Time / s');ylabel('Voltage / V');
set(gca,'FontSize',fontsize, 'LineWidth',2,'TickLength',[0.025 0.025])
xticks([0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]);
ylim([-2, 2]),

yyaxis left
top = plot(t ,T, 'Linewidth',3); hold all;
xlabel('Time / s');ylabel('Temperature / K');
chH = get(gca,'Children');
set(gca,'Children',[chH(end);chH(1:end-1)]);
% uistack(top, 'top');

ax = gca;
ax.YAxis(2).MinorTick = 'on';
ax.YAxis(2).MinorTickValues = 0:0.05:1;
ax.YAxis(1).MinorTick = 'on';
ax.YAxis(1).MinorTickValues = 250:50:650;
```